# Error after changing to less compilation in admin

Tags: magento2.2.2, less-compilation

I am pretty new to magento. After I change to client-side less compilation. I get the following.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: template in 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php on line 
357

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: template in 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php on line 
357
#0 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(357): 
Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', 
'/var/www/html/v...', 357, Array)
#1 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(239): 
Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer-
>renderAssetHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#2 
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(226): 
Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer-
>renderAssetGroup(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Asset\PropertyGroup))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-
developer/Model/View/Page/Config/ClientSideLessCompilation/Renderer.php(87): 
Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderAssets(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php(99): 
Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\ClientSideLessCompilation\Renderer-
>renderAssets(Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(249): 
Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer->renderHeadContent()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(170): 
Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page-
>render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): 
Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout-
>renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): 
Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor-
>___callParent('renderResult', Array)
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): 
Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor-
>Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}
(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#10
/var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.
php(26): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor-
>___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): 
Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor-
>renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): 
Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#13 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap-
>run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#14 {main}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear **/var/www/html/generated** folder and clear cache. If that doesn't help - just redeploy static content after you clear **/var/www/html/generated** and **/var/www/html/var/view_preprocesed** folders

Comment: I have already tried both. Didn't seem to help.